# what is the use of node js binary in meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

We team planned to develop an app with Meteor.

What is the use of node js in meteor?

So far googled, i found that when we are installing Meteor, it will download something called dev_bundle which has NodeJS and all the NPM modules needed by Meteor. All these modules are pre-compiled for our platform.

Do we need to learn node js to work with meteor?

Please guide me.

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: At the very minimum npm is a javascript script that runs on node.js. Without node you can't run npm. While meteor itself is a webkit based interpreter for javascript apps most of the command line tools you'll be using (like npm for example) don't run on meteor. They run on node.js instead because they don't need to load all the GUI stuff. Think of the difference between the meteor interpreter and node.js like the difference between google chrome and firefox.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like I got it a bit wrong. Meteor doesn't come with a custom interpreter. Meteor is javascript code running on top of node.js. So think of meteor as something like jQuery and think of node.js as something like firefox.

Comment: fine. then the developer no need to learn or worry about node.js(firefox) to work with meteor(jQuery) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor is a node.js framework. Node is what's happening "under the hood". You do not need to learn node to get started with meteor. Simply speaking, frameworks(like this) are just higher level architecture to help you "write less, do more". You can read more about meteor here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_(web_framework)